# I've got a critical error happening: a variety of deep and persistent graphical freak-outs, with occasional crashes and freezes. Is it Ubuntu or...?

Tags: graphics

**It's an intermittent problem of varying intensity**- it can work absolutely fine for minutes or hours. It varies from mildly distracting to completely unusable. The problem can appear intractable or persist for half an hour and then work fine again.

**The main nature of it is a graphical failure, and seems to come in lots of different flavors**: whole screen going suddenly, randomly pixelated; splices of images that were on the screen in the last few minutes being spliced and forming a collage (even drawing from beyond restarts), sometimes being trail-cleared by the movement of the mouse; chunks and lines of colors making some sort of checkers board of parts of the screen; some windows being all black; text being overlayed in multiple phantoms of various colors. Just quite random really.

I don't know what triggers it- working fine and then it turns on a dime. And back again.

**Inputs usually still work**- to some degree- for example I've been able to play a video with the audio working but the screen looking like a poorly drawn snowstorm.

**Very rarely it freezes, sometimes crashes and returns to the login screen, or resets itself.** As a rule this doesn't result in an improvement of the graphic issues.

**The issues persist into the tty consoles**- usually not as bad but yeah the text starts to flicker into random colors and become unresponsive.

**I assume it's deeper than Ubuntu as it also appears on startup as often as not**. It will get through startup but I might not always be able to navigate login.

**I first encountered this problem when using Ubuntu 20.04, and it's stuck around through several installations of 22.04.**

Immediately after this first arose I for the first time saw a message on startup about orphaned iodes, "dev/sda3:clean..." and blocks etc. I'm of the understanding such a message is fine but I'm wondering if that offers a clue to what happened.

I've had pieces of hardware swapped in and out and tested, with no faults found... maybe because of how intermittent it can be.

The latest setup has seen me install different NVIDIA drivers (turns out ones too advanced for my actual hardware so they're currently being ignored) so I'm in a pretty basic graphics mode which... might be working better... but still has issues.

Fresh installs seemed to offer some short periods of stability but my last attempt was thwarted seemingly by this same issue, quite close to the installation being finalized.

I've a 'System Profiler and Benchmark' report available if that helps. Let me know what else could assist in diagnosing. I'd love to solve this issue, or move on if it's beyond redemption.

Comment: Please try and be specific.  You didn't give details of what Ubuntu 20.04 LTS system you were using, as a fully upgraded 20.04 LTS desktop using the GA kernel will be using 5.4 which differs greatly to the 5.15 used by Ubuntu 22.04 LTS (GA/HWE currently).  However a 20.04 LTS system fully-upgraded but using HWE will also be using the 5.15 kernel just like 22.04; if using HWE but not fully-upgraded it'll be using 5.13.. but you've given no clear specific details - only release details. What *flavors* and what ISO & kernel stack was used? 20.04/20.04.1 *flavor* ISOs 20.04.2 & later HWE so which?

Comment: If a re-install of say 20.04 is fine until it updates; that maybe a sign that you're install a HWE kernel that is oudated (so 5.13 or older!) but upgrades to 5.15 that is used by 22.04 which your system didn't like.  If however you installed 22.04 using a GA default ISO, or ISO that lets you select kernel stack; a 20.04 LTS system remains on 5.4 kernel meaning you either won't have an issue if your hardware doesn't like 5.15, **or** your issue is unrelated to kernel stack. You provided no specific details on what 20.04 ISO/product & thus kernel stack you tried/having issues with, nor *flavors*